# Instagram "this user does not exist" error in live mode

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm getting the following error when hitting the get recent media endpoint of instagram:

```
"error_type": "APINotFoundError",
"code": 400,
"error_message": "this user does not exist"
```

Points to note:
1) App is in live mode, the basic permission has been approved. I didnt apply for any other permission.
2) Works fine for sandbox user

This is the exact URL i'm hitting:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2147483647/media/recent/?access_token=

Am I missing something or do I have to explicitly do something to put the app into live mode ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that the user id **2147483647** does not correspond to a valid Instagram user. I just tried on my end and I get the same response.

P.S: You should NEVER post your **access_token** in public posts such as these. You should mask it from the post ASAP.

Comment: @Ankit You do know, editing a question in SO always keeps a history. You should probably revoke the access token, just in case.